# Python3 installation failed, Error code 0x80070003

Tags: python-3.x

**Python3 installation failed, error code 0x80070003.**

My system is windows 10 64 bit, The installed version is 3.6.2

[Installation error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVMef.png)

**The error log：**

```
[2C1C:40E8][2018-01-15T12:32:04]e314: Failed to cache payload: core_AllUsers from working path: C:\Users\WESTIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{E8A75A81-A084-498C-865F-D7D322105665}\core_AllUsers, error: 0x80070003.
[2C1C:3D2C][2018-01-15T12:32:04]e000: Error 0x80070003: Cache thread exited unexpectedly.
[2C1C:3D2C][2018-01-15T12:32:04]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{f71cfe9a-4a67-48a6-844b-571a76b33d33}, resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: No
[2C1C:3D2C][2018-01-15T12:32:04]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{f71cfe9a-4a67-48a6-844b-571a76b33d33}, resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[2C1C:3D2C][2018-01-15T12:32:04]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070003, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No*
```

Comment: Looks like https://bugs.python.org/issue29702 .. consider installing any available Windows updates.

Comment: Thank you. I'll see if this solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

when you perform the installation and choose the "Download debugging symbols" or "Download debug binaries", make sure your internet connection is up and available otherwise un-check those.